# Python Multiprocessing - alternate multi-process and single-process executions

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to implement a data collection and processing algorithm that works by continuously alternating two stages:

1. N processes collect a list of K values each and then wait
2. The main process collects the N * K values from the processes and performs some operations on them
3. The main process signals the N processes that they can start to collect new values again, and waits
4. Repeat from 1

I'm trying to achieve this using `multiprocessing` in Python 3.9, but I think I'm doing it very wrong.

I have a `Generator` class that generates the values, and I use a semaphore with `value` equal to the number of processes. The goal would be that

1. All processes acquire 1 -> the semaphore cannot be acquired anymore -> main process has to wait
2. All process finish and release the semaphore -> when all semaphores are released, the main can continue
3. Main acquires all semaphores, blocking the processes to collect new data
4. Main finishes, releases the semaphores, and we go back to 1.

This does not work because 3 never happens since when a process finishes it immediately re-acquires the semaphore. I could solve this by adding some additional semaphores or locks, but I feel there is a proper way of achieving what I'm trying to do by using some appropriate classes in the multiprocessing package, but I cannot find any reference to the type of architecture I'm trying to implement. Could you point me to something related?

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


class Generator:

    def __init__(self, process_id: int, semaphore: mp.Semaphore):
        self.process_id = process_id
        self.semaphore = semaphore
        self.buffer = []

    def generate(self, n):
        while True:
            self.semaphore.acquire()
            for i in range(n):
                self.buffer.append(i)
                time.sleep(3)
            print(f'Process: {self.process_id}, buffer: {self.buffer}')
            self.semaphore.release()

    def get_values(self):
        """Empty the buffer and return the values
        """
        print(f'Getting values from {self.process_id}: {self.buffer}')
        values = self.buffer
        self.buffer = []
        return values


if __name__ == '__main__':

    n_proc = 4
    coord_semaphore = mp.Semaphore(n_proc)

    processes = []
    generators = []
    for proc_num in range(n_proc):
        gen = Generator(proc_num, coord_semaphore)
        proc = mp.Process(target=gen.generate, args=(2,))
        processes.append(proc)
        generators.append(gen)

    # Start all processes
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    print('Processes started')
    time.sleep(0.5)

    while True:
        # Acquire all semaphores
        print('Waiting for processes to collect data')
        for _ in processes:
            coord_semaphore.acquire()
        print('All processes have collected enough data')

        all_values = []
        for g in generators:
            vals = g.get_values()
            all_values.extend(vals)
        print(f'Got from processes: {all_values}')
        
        for _ in processes:
            coord_semaphore.release()
```

Comment: There is no need to lock anything here. Just make a proces which generates K values, signals that it is done and then waits for a signal to continue. You can use `Event` for the signals. On the other hand, you have to figure out how to send the data back to the main process. And then there is also the question whether the whole thing is a good idea at all...

Comment: @zvone Thanks, I'll try! About whether it's a good idea at all, the data processing done by the main process requires operating on the whole batch of data. I'm using multiprocessing just to parallelize the data collection part

Comment: The point is that parallelizing stuff can make it faster or slower, depending on details.